# LARAVEL - PASSPORT - Expires_at column not verified in token validation

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I noticed that the expires_at column from the "oauth_access_tokens" table is not checked during the token validation, which grants access to users with expired tokens.

For testing, I've used the sample application in the repository below:

https://github.com/neoighodaro/laravel-passport-demo

After running "`php artisan passport:install`" command, I manually updated the "expires_at" column to a date in the past.

But, the consumer service could still retrieve the results, even with the token expired.

I checked the MYSQL log using :

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

And the executed query was:

```
select * from `oauth_access_tokens` where `oauth_access_tokens`.`id` = '3e19b972734fcfdf7951de363fc5e9aeab9ea962cf0de7d686a6d2805879d1c4cfa624973eec6ebf' limit 1
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
select * from `oauth_access_tokens` where `oauth_access_tokens`.`id` = '3e19b972734fcfdf7951de363fc5e9aeab9ea962cf0de7d686a6d2805879d1c4cfa624973eec6ebf' and revoked = 0 and expires_at >= <Carbon::now()> limit 1
```

?